# onclick - change cell background color, but with dynamic contents

Tags: jquery

This code works and does what I want to do. All cells containing a certain value are highlighted when clicked on.
However, the real contents of these cells are dynamid. The number of rows and columns too. How can I make this code dynamic?
(the cell content is always a single lower case word with underscrores, so it could be used as a valid class value.)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".one").click(function(){
        $("td").removeClass("blue");
        $("td.one").addClass("blue");
      });

      $(".two").click(function(){
        $("td").removeClass("blue");
        $("td.two").addClass("blue");
      });

      $(".three").click(function(){
        $("td").removeClass("blue");
        $("td.three").addClass("blue");
      });
    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .blue {background-color:lightblue;}
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <table border=1>
        <tr><td class="one">one</td>    <td class="three">three</td><td class="two">two</td>    </tr>
        <tr><td class="two">two</td>    <td class="two">two</td>    <td class="three">three</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="three">three</td><td class="one">one</td>    <td class="one">one</td>    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to target elements with the same class names as the clicked element, just get the class name of the targeted element and then use that to target the other elements with the same classnames:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table border=1>
        <tr><td class="one">one</td>    <td class="three">three</td><td class="two">two</td>    </tr>
        <tr><td class="two">two</td>    <td class="two">two</td>    <td class="three">three</td></tr>
        <tr><td class="three">three</td><td class="one">one</td>    <td class="one">one</td>    </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

In your CSS file (Using a meaningful classname that separates the color from the function.)

```
.highlighted {background-color:light blue;}
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $("table td").on("click", function(e){
     $("table td").toggleClass("highlighted", false);
     var sel = $(e.target).attr("class").replace(/\b(\w+)/, '.$1');
     $(sel).toggleClass("highlighted", true);            
  });
});
```

Here's [a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vaxiy/3/) that shows the working example